# Expected size of a probabilistic set

Tags: mean, expected-value

Suppose I have a set $X$ such that each element $x$ is associated with a probability $p_x$. Now suppose I build another set $Y$ from the elements in $X$ such that the probability of $x$ appearing in $Y$ is $p_x$.

Am I correct in thinking that the mean or "expected" size of $Y$ is the sum of these probabilities, i.e., $E(|Y|) = \sum_{x \in X}p_x$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each term $x$ in $\mathfrak X$ is drawn with probability $p_x$, marginally (that is, not necessarily independently of the other draws), the size of the resulting set $\mathfrak Y$
is given by
$$|\mathfrak Y|=\sum_{x\in \mathfrak X}\mathbb I_\mathfrak Y(x)$$
and its expected value is
$$\mathbb E[|\mathfrak Y|]=\sum_{x\in \mathfrak X}\mathbb E[\mathbb I_\mathfrak Y(x)]=\sum_{x\in \mathfrak X}\mathbb P[\mathfrak Y\ni x]=\sum_{x\in \mathfrak X}p_x$$